# Will upgrading weblogic server from 10.3 to 12 cause any issues to OBIEE 11g installation?

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, obiee

We have OBIEE 11g installed on our server. We are planning to upgrade Weblogic 10.3 that is running on the same server to Weblogic 12. Will this cause any issues to the OBIEE 11g installation?

Is there anywhere I can check compatibility between OBIEE & Weblogic versions? Does weblogic and obiee come as a single package or as separate packages?

Comment: Compatibility information is all available through Oracle's support website. As it's not related to programming, this question might be more appropriate for ServerFault or one of the other sister sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "OBIEE certification matrix" and in the oracle site you can check the xls of your specific version.

In these excels there is extensive information about the compatibility between the product and any related software, such supported databases or application servers.

Comment: thank you. I got help from oracle support team and came to know that OBI  11g will not work with weblogic 12.